# How to stop media player on back pressed regardless of whether it's playing or not?

Tags: java, android, media-player, back

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    mp.release();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim, R.anim.anim2);
}
```

MediaPlayer is released when a sound is being played, however when a sound isn't being played it can't release anything and causes a null pointer. If I don't release it then it continues to play. It's a catch 22. How can I basically stop MediaPlayer regardless without any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

release the media player in this manner

```
if(mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()){
             mp.release();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a flag.Whenever media is playing,make that flag true.

```
int playingFlag = 0;
```

//Make this playing flag 1 when media is playing,by making its value 1

```
playingFlag = 1;
```

//When media stops,make this flag as 0

```
playingFlag = 0;
```

//In your onBackPressed method,check this flag.If it is 1,stop the player,if its 0,do nothing.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    if( playingFlag == 1 ) {
       //Do something you want
       mp.release();
       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim, R.anim.anim2);
    } else {
        //Do nothing
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

Check whether media player is playing

```
if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying())
     mp.release();
```